# Visual Studio Code: How to define key bindings for page-home and page-end

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

Whilst coding I frequently find myself needing to jump either to the top or bottom of a file, but I can't find a quick way to do this with a single key stroke. I tried to define a short cut in the key bindings, but I can't find a function like "page-home" and "page-end". I was going to use the alt key with the home button to jump to the top of a page and alt+end for the bottom.

ie I was expecting to be able to define say:

> { "key": "alt+home", "command": "[what is page home command]", "when":
>   "terminalFocus"}

So, are there such functions page-home/page-end (I may have this wrong, perhaps its defined as something else).

I've spotted a binding for "cmd+home" bound to "workbench.action.terminal.scrollToTop" which sounds like the right function (and a similar one for "cmd+end"), but they don't work.

UPDATE: I've tried to apply changes to the keybindings via the key bindings page, by defining the keystrokes I mentioned before, and it still does not work. Unless I'm doing something wrong, I . think there is a bug that needs to be reported, unless somebody can say otherwise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31811#issuecomment-323183322). The commands you're looking for are `cursorTop` and `cursorBottom`.

Open up the command palette (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Windows) and select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts File`

Add in the following settings in `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+home",
    "command": "cursorTop",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+end",
    "command": "cursorBottom",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

replacing the key with whatever shortcut you prefer.

Comment: changing ctrl to cmd is also favoured (in iMac) thanks.